# How do i solve HTTP Error with asp upload in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, http, google-chrome, asp-classic

I got some problems with the Jquery plugin Uploadify working with the Aspfreeupload code. Its working in IE but in chrome and firefox it crash. The HTTP response is **HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized**
I think the error is in the asp code:

```vb
const DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE = 200000

const adModeReadWrite = 3
const adTypeBinary = 1
const adTypeText = 2
const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

Class FreeASPUpload
Public UploadedFiles
Public FormElements

Private VarArrayBinRequest
Private StreamRequest
Private uploadedYet
Private internalChunkSize

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set UploadedFiles = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set FormElements = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set StreamRequest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    StreamRequest.Type = adTypeText
    StreamRequest.Open
    uploadedYet = false
    internalChunkSize = DEFAULT_ASP_CHUNK_SIZE
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    If IsObject(UploadedFiles) Then
        UploadedFiles.RemoveAll()
        Set UploadedFiles = Nothing
    End If
    If IsObject(FormElements) Then
        FormElements.RemoveAll()
        Set FormElements = Nothing
    End If
    StreamRequest.Close
    Set StreamRequest = Nothing
End Sub

Public Property Get Form(sIndex)
    Form = ""
    If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Form = FormElements.Item(LCase(sIndex))
End Property

Public Property Get Files()
    Files = UploadedFiles.Items
End Property

Public Property Get Exists(sIndex)
        Exists = false
        If FormElements.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) Then Exists = true
End Property

Public Property Get FileExists(sIndex)
    FileExists = false
        if UploadedFiles.Exists(LCase(sIndex)) then FileExists = true
End Property

Public Property Get chunkSize()
    chunkSize = internalChunkSize
End Property

Public Property Let chunkSize(sz)
    internalChunkSize = sz
End Property

'Calls Upload to extract the data from the binary request and then saves the uploaded files
Public Sub Save(path)
    Dim streamFile, fileItem, filePath

    if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

    if not uploadedYet then Upload

    For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
        filePath = path & fileItem.FileName
        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile filePath, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = filePath
     Next
End Sub

public sub SaveOne(path, num, byref outFileName, byref outLocalFileName)
    Dim streamFile, fileItems, fileItem, fs

    set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    if Right(path, 1) <> "\" then path = path & "\"

    if not uploadedYet then Upload
    if UploadedFiles.Count > 0 then
        fileItems = UploadedFiles.Items
        set fileItem = fileItems(num)

        outFileName = fileItem.FileName
        outLocalFileName = GetFileName(path, outFileName)

        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position = fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile path & outLocalFileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = path & filename
    end if
end sub

Public Function SaveBinRequest(path) ' For debugging purposes
    StreamRequest.SaveToFile path & "\debugStream.bin", 2
End Function

Public Sub DumpData() 'only works if files are plain text
    Dim i, aKeys, f
    response.write "Form Items:<br>"
    aKeys = FormElements.Keys
    For i = 0 To FormElements.Count -1 ' Iterate the array
        response.write aKeys(i) & " = " & FormElements.Item(aKeys(i)) & "<BR>"
    Next
    response.write "Uploaded Files:<br>"
    For Each f In UploadedFiles.Items
        response.write "Name: " & f.FileName & "<br>"
        response.write "Type: " & f.ContentType & "<br>"
        response.write "Start: " & f.Start & "<br>"
        response.write "Size: " & f.Length & "<br>"
     Next
End Sub

Public Sub Upload()
    Dim nCurPos, nDataBoundPos, nLastSepPos
    Dim nPosFile, nPosBound
    Dim sFieldName, osPathSep, auxStr
    Dim readBytes, readLoop, tmpBinRequest

    'RFC1867 Tokens
    Dim vDataSep
    Dim tNewLine, tDoubleQuotes, tTerm, tFilename, tName, tContentDisp, tContentType
    tNewLine = String2Byte(Chr(13))
    tDoubleQuotes = String2Byte(Chr(34))
    tTerm = String2Byte("--")
    tFilename = String2Byte("filename=""")
    tName = String2Byte("name=""")
    tContentDisp = String2Byte("Content-Disposition")
    tContentType = String2Byte("Content-Type:")

    uploadedYet = true

    on error resume next
        ' Copy binary request to a byte array, on which functions like InstrB and others can be used to search for separation tokens
        readBytes = internalChunkSize
        VarArrayBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
        VarArrayBinRequest = midb(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, lenb(VarArrayBinRequest))
        Do Until readBytes < 1
            tmpBinRequest = Request.BinaryRead(readBytes)
            if readBytes > 0 then
                VarArrayBinRequest = VarArrayBinRequest & midb(tmpBinRequest, 1, lenb(tmpBinRequest))
            end if
        Loop
        StreamRequest.WriteText(VarArrayBinRequest)
        StreamRequest.Flush()
        if Err.Number <> 0 then 
            response.write "<br><br><B>System reported this error:</B><p>"
            response.write Err.Description & "<p>"
            response.write "The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
            Exit Sub
        end if
    on error goto 0 'reset error handling

    nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine,1) 'Note: nCurPos is 1-based (and so is InstrB, MidB, etc)

    If nCurPos <= 1  Then Exit Sub

    'vDataSep is a separator like -----------------------------21763138716045
    vDataSep = MidB(VarArrayBinRequest, 1, nCurPos-1)

    'Start of current separator
    nDataBoundPos = 1

    'Beginning of last line
    nLastSepPos = FindToken(vDataSep & tTerm, 1)

    Do Until nDataBoundPos = nLastSepPos

        nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentDisp, nDataBoundPos)
        nCurPos = SkipToken(tName, nCurPos)
        sFieldName = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)

        nPosFile = FindToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
        nPosBound = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)

        If nPosFile <> 0 And  nPosFile < nPosBound Then
            Dim oUploadFile
            Set oUploadFile = New UploadedFile

            nCurPos = SkipToken(tFilename, nCurPos)
            auxStr = ExtractField(tDoubleQuotes, nCurPos)
            ' We are interested only in the name of the file, not the whole path
            ' Path separator is \ in windows, / in UNIX
            ' While IE seems to put the whole pathname in the stream, Mozilla seem to 
            ' only put the actual file name, so UNIX paths may be rare. But not impossible.
            osPathSep = "\"
            if InStr(auxStr, osPathSep) = 0 then osPathSep = "/"
            oUploadFile.FileName = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, osPathSep))

            if (Len(oUploadFile.FileName) > 0) then 'File field not left empty
                nCurPos = SkipToken(tContentType, nCurPos)

                auxStr = ExtractField(tNewLine, nCurPos)
                ' NN on UNIX puts things like this in the stream:
                '    ?? python py type=?? python application/x-python
                oUploadFile.ContentType = Right(auxStr, Len(auxStr)-InStrRev(auxStr, " "))
                nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line

                oUploadFile.Start = nCurPos+1
                oUploadFile.Length = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2 - nCurPos

                If oUploadFile.Length > 0 Then UploadedFiles.Add LCase(sFieldName), oUploadFile
            End If
        Else
            Dim nEndOfData, fieldValueUniStr
            nCurPos = FindToken(tNewLine, nCurPos) + 4 'skip empty line
            nEndOfData = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos) - 2
            fieldValueuniStr = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nCurPos, nEndOfData-nCurPos)
            If Not FormElements.Exists(LCase(sFieldName)) Then 
                FormElements.Add LCase(sFieldName), fieldValueuniStr
            else
                FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName))= FormElements.Item(LCase(sFieldName)) & ", " & fieldValueuniStr
            end if 

        End If

        'Advance to next separator
        nDataBoundPos = FindToken(vDataSep, nCurPos)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Function SkipToken(sToken, nStart)
    SkipToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
    If SkipToken = 0 then
        Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request. The most likely cause for this error is the incorrect setup of AspMaxRequestEntityAllowed in IIS MetaBase. Please see instructions in the <A HREF='http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/requirements.asp'>requirements page of freeaspupload.net</A>.<p>"
        Response.End
    end if
    SkipToken = SkipToken + LenB(sToken)
End Function

Private Function FindToken(sToken, nStart)
    FindToken = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
End Function

Private Function ExtractField(sToken, nStart)
    Dim nEnd
    nEnd = InstrB(nStart, VarArrayBinRequest, sToken)
    If nEnd = 0 then
        Response.write "Error in parsing uploaded binary request."
        Response.End
    end if
    ExtractField = ConvertUtf8BytesToString(nStart, nEnd-nStart)
End Function

'String to byte string conversion
Private Function String2Byte(sString)
    Dim i
    For i = 1 to Len(sString)
       String2Byte = String2Byte & ChrB(AscB(Mid(sString,i,1)))
    Next
End Function

Private Function ConvertUtf8BytesToString(start, length)    
    StreamRequest.Position = 0

    Dim objStream
    Dim strTmp

    ' init stream
    Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    objStream.Charset = "utf-8"
    objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
    objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
    objStream.Open

    ' write bytes into stream
    StreamRequest.Position = start+1
    StreamRequest.CopyTo objStream, length
    objStream.Flush

    ' rewind stream and read text
    objStream.Position = 0
    objStream.Type = adTypeText
    strTmp = objStream.ReadText

    ' close up and return
    objStream.Close
    Set objStream = Nothing
    ConvertUtf8BytesToString = strTmp   
End Function
End Class

Class UploadedFile
Public ContentType
Public Start
Public Length
Public Path
Private nameOfFile

' Need to remove characters that are valid in UNIX, but not in Windows
Public Property Let FileName(fN)
    nameOfFile = fN
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "\", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "/", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ":", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "*", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "?", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, """", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "<", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, ">", "_")
    nameOfFile = SubstNoReg(nameOfFile, "|", "_")
End Property

Public Property Get FileName()
    FileName = nameOfFile
End Property

'Public Property Get FileN()ame
End Class


' Does not depend on RegEx, which is not available on older VBScript
' Is not recursive, which means it will not run out of stack space
Function SubstNoReg(initialStr, oldStr, newStr)
Dim currentPos, oldStrPos, skip
If IsNull(initialStr) Or Len(initialStr) = 0 Then
    SubstNoReg = ""
ElseIf IsNull(oldStr) Or Len(oldStr) = 0 Then
    SubstNoReg = initialStr
Else
    If IsNull(newStr) Then newStr = ""
    currentPos = 1
    oldStrPos = 0
    SubstNoReg = ""
    skip = Len(oldStr)
    Do While currentPos <= Len(initialStr)
        oldStrPos = InStr(currentPos, initialStr, oldStr)
        If oldStrPos = 0 Then
            SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, Len(initialStr) - currentPos + 1)
            currentPos = Len(initialStr) + 1
        Else
            SubstNoReg = SubstNoReg & Mid(initialStr, currentPos, oldStrPos - currentPos) & newStr
            currentPos = oldStrPos + skip
        End If
    Loop
End If
End Function

Function GetFileName(strSaveToPath, FileName)
'This function is used when saving a file to check there is not already a file with the same name so that you don't overwrite it.
'It adds numbers to the filename e.g. file.gif becomes file1.gif becomes file2.gif and so on.
'It keeps going until it returns a filename that does not exist.
'You could just create a filename from the ID field but that means writing the record - and it still might exist!
'N.B. Requires strSaveToPath variable to be available - and containing the path to save to
Dim Counter
Dim Flag
Dim strTempFileName
Dim FileExt
Dim NewFullPath
dim objFSO, p
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Counter = 0
p = instrrev(FileName, ".")
FileExt = mid(FileName, p+1)
strTempFileName = left(FileName, p-1)
NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & FileName
Flag = False

Do Until Flag = True
    If objFSO.FileExists(NewFullPath) = False Then
        Flag = True
        GetFileName = Mid(NewFullPath, InstrRev(NewFullPath, "\") + 1)
    Else
        Counter = Counter + 1
        NewFullPath = strSaveToPath & "\" & strTempFileName & Counter & "." & FileExt
    End If
Loop
End Function
```

Any Ideas?

**::EDIT::**
Im adding more of the code that i missed:

```vb
Response.Expires = -1
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600
' All communication must be in UTF-8, including the response back from the request
Session.CodePage  = 65001

<!-- #include file="freeaspupload.asp" -->





Dim uploadsDirVar
uploadsDirVar = "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\admindoit\uploadedimages\kampanjimg" 


function OutputForm()

end function

function TestEnvironment()
Dim fso, fileName, testFile, streamTest
TestEnvironment = ""
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
if not fso.FolderExists(uploadsDirVar) then
    TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not exist.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
    exit function
end if
fileName = uploadsDirVar & "\test.txt"
on error resume next
Set testFile = fso.CreateTextFile(fileName, true)
If Err.Number<>0 then
    TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have write permissions.</B><br>The value of your uploadsDirVar is incorrect. Open uploadTester.asp in an editor and change the value of uploadsDirVar to the pathname of a directory with write permissions."
    exit function
end if
Err.Clear
testFile.Close
fso.DeleteFile(fileName)
If Err.Number<>0 then
    TestEnvironment = "<B>Folder " & uploadsDirVar & " does not have delete permissions</B>, although it does have write permissions.<br>Change the permissions for IUSR_<I>computername</I> on  this folder."
    exit function
end if
Err.Clear
Set streamTest = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
If Err.Number<>0 then
    TestEnvironment = "<B>The ADODB object <I>Stream</I> is not available in your    server.</B><br>Check the Requirements page for information about upgrading your ADODB libraries."
    exit function
end if
Set streamTest = Nothing
end function

function SaveFiles
Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey

Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

' If something fails inside the script, but the exception is handled
If Err.Number<>0 then Exit function

SaveFiles = ""


end function


<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Test Free ASP Upload 2.0</TITLE>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
BODY {background-color: white;font-family:arial; font-size:12}
</style>
<script>
function onSubmitForm() {
var formDOMObj = document.frmSend;
if (formDOMObj.attach1.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach2.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach3.value == "" && formDOMObj.attach4.value == "" )
    alert("Please press the Browse button and pick a file.")
else
    return true;
return false;
}
</script>

</HEAD>

<BODY>




<%
Dim diagnostics
if Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") <> "POST" then
diagnostics = TestEnvironment()
if diagnostics<>"" then
    response.write "<div style=""margin-left:20; margin-top:30; margin-right:30; margin-bottom:30;"">"
    response.write diagnostics
    response.write "<p>After you correct this problem, reload the page."
    response.write "</div>"
else
    response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
    OutputForm()
    response.write "</div>"
end if
else
response.write "<div style=""margin-left:150"">"
OutputForm()
response.write SaveFiles()
response.write "<br><br></div>"
end if

%>




</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**PROBLEM SOLVED! The error was not in the code, the server didn't give Chrome write permission!
Thanks anyway**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about capturing the HTTP response and posting it?

Comment: Hi again! The HTTP response is : HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized